# How will this circuit work

Tags: power, capacitor, resistors, switch-mode-power-supply, filter

**[image: strong text]**

This circuit is after the rectification process how will this work

Comment: What's it supposed to do?  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Have you tried simulating it? Where does it come from?

Comment: Hints: (1) Why do we use capacitors after the rectifier? (2) What happens when you put two capacitors in series. (3) Why might you put a potential divider in parallel? (4) Why have 2 x 220k instead of 1 x 440k? [Edit] your best efforts into your question.

Comment: It is basically for filter purpose ..but how is it different from normal RC filter?

Comment: @AkankshaUpadhyay:  It doesn't look like any kind of a filter.  Is this some kind of high voltage DC power supply?  Something with an output over 350VDC?

Comment: I am unable to understand the arrangemet!

Comment: Is it a high voltage power supply?

Comment: yes it's a power supply .This is the part after input rectification.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is part of a DC power supply. It is using two electrolytic capacitors in series to achieve the required voltage rating which, presumably, exceeds 350 V DC.

When you series connect capacitors like this the voltage across them will be in inverse proportion to the real capacitance value (as opposed to the rated value printed on the capacitor). Electrolytics have a wide tolerance and ±20% wouldn't be unusual.

The resistors help balance out the voltages on the capacitors to prevent excess voltage on either one. 2 × 220k is chosen to avoid exceeding the voltage rating of the resistors.

The resistors will also discharge the capacitors when the circuit is powered off. This is generally a good idea. For an exercise, can you calculate how long it will take for the voltage to drop to 5% of the powered-on value?